# MSW (Mock Service Worker) change port from 8080

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, service-worker, intercept

The [MSW documentation for request-url](https://mswjs.io/docs/basics/request-matching#request-url) says:

```js
// Only "POST https://api.backend.dev/users" requests match this handler
rest.post('https://api.backend.dev/users', responseResolver)
// Given your application runs on "http://localhost:8080",
// this request handler URL gets resolved to "http://localhost:8080/invoices"
rest.get('/invoices', invocesResolver)
```

Been searching a lot but can't find some docs on how to change the port. So it could be something like `http://localhost:3001`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "localhost:8080" is emphasized above because a relative URL against a default `localhost` will resolve to `localhost:8080/url`. You don't necessarily have to customize that.

### Relative URL

Any relative URL will be relative against the current application's location. So if your application is running on `http://localhost:3000` and you defined a relative `/user` handler, you get `http://localhost:3000/user` automatically.

```js
// If my app runs on :3000, the handler above intercepts
// a GET http://localhost:3000/user. I don't have to specify
// hostnames/ports for relative URLs against the application address.
rest.get('/user', resolver)
```

### Absolute URL

If you need (for some reason) to define a handler for an *external* localhost service, the one that is *not* your application, you include its absolute URL:

```js
// My app runs on :3000 but I want to intercept and mock a request
// to another app that runs on localhost:3001. Here's how I do it:
rest.get('http://localhost:3001/user', resolver)
```

Comment: I'm using the MSW/node to mock out the rest API (a different application). Was just wondering if there was a  way to set the baseURL since it's a react native application so there will be no application running on localhost 8080 (or 3000) all fetch request will go to the API application on 3001

Comment: Then my suggestion about the absolute URL is the one to follow. You can abstract the base URL, if it's repetitive, into a function that composes the absolute URL given a relative path.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and tip 